# Amazon Custom zip now returning empty

Tags: api, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

Amazon Custom orders normally come in like this through the Reports API. (https://zme-caps.amazon.com/t/randomstring/randomstring/1 after the country is the link to the zip)

104-7327504-xxxxxxx      [More Data Here]       US        https://zme-caps.amazon.com/t/randomstring/randomstring/1        http://a.co/randomstring        false

Since 4:00PM today they are coming in like this (No more zip link, blank instead).

113-7408936-xxxxxxx       [More Data Here]       US                        false

What is causing this and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Amazon and they have acknowledged that it is an issue on their end that they are working on resolving now.